# group result of query by week (7 days) - MySql

Tags: mysql

I have this query that outputs (sorted) the date of each day and the count per day from the 03-03-2017 until now. Is there a way to group it by week (7 days)?

query.sql:

```
SELECT SUM(a.ctr)
,a.datecreated
FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as ctr, date_format(created, '%d/%m/%y ') as datecreated 
    FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
    GROUP BY date(datecreated)
    UNION ALL 
    select 0 as ctr, date_format(selected_date,  '%d/%m/%y ') as datecreated 
       from 
     (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
    where selected_date 
    between (SELECT MIN(created) FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips)
        and (SELECT MAX(created) FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips)
) a
group by date(a.datecreated)
order by month(a.datecreated), date(a.datecreated)
```

result (part of it):

```
'279',  '03/03/17'
'40',   '04/03/17'
'41',   '05/03/17'
'1223', '06/03/17'
'493',  '07/03/17'
'580',  '08/03/17'
'829',  '09/03/17'
'936',  '10/03/17'
'638',  '11/03/17'
'345',  '12/03/17'
'876',  '13/03/17'
'1583', '14/03/17'
'1566', '15/03/17'
'1772', '16/03/17'
```

wanted result:

```
'3485',  '03/03/17'
'7716',  '10/03/17'
```

***EDIT:*** results using group by week(a.datecreated):

```
'38657', '03/03/17 '
'4773', '07/03/17 '
'28529', '01/04/17 '
'14191', '05/04/17 '
'34223', '01/05/17 '
'43093', '04/05/17 '
'82515', '01/06/17 '
'1804', '12/06/17 '
'23513', '01/07/17 '
'9287', '05/07/17 '
```

**P.S:**
It would be perfect if the week (7 days) could start from the 5th of march 2017 (05-03-2017) since that is a monday and the 3rd and 4th will be left as single numbers

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @Strawberry please help me instead of just linking stuff

Comment: When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less. In this instance, the accepted answer at the link provided says everything I would want to say.

Comment: @Strawberry You are downvoter??

Comment: @Strawberry why would you downvote the answer tho? I can understand the downvote for the question but not for the answer... C'mon man

Comment: @SagarGangwal FWIW, it's not my downvote

Comment: @Strawberry You can nullify the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(a.ctr)
,a.datecreated
FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as ctr, date_format(created, '%d/%m/%y ') as datecreated 
    FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
    GROUP BY date(datecreated)
    UNION ALL 
    select 0 as ctr, date_format(selected_date,  '%d/%m/%y ') as datecreated 
       from 
     (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
    where selected_date 
    between (SELECT MIN(created) FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips)
        and (SELECT MAX(created) FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips)
) a
group by week(STR_TO_DATE(a.datecreated,'%d/%m/%y'))
order by month(a.datecreated), date(a.datecreated)
```

Using this line `group by week(STR_TO_DATE(a.datecreated,'%d/%m/%y'))`.

You are converting your string field to Date and then convert that date into week.

You can try above query.

Comment: already tried this and doesn't work.
results (all of them):
`'38657', '03/03/17 '
'4773', '07/03/17 '
'28529', '01/04/17 '
'14191', '05/04/17 '
'34223', '01/05/17 '
'43093', '04/05/17 '
'82515', '01/06/17 '
'1804', '12/06/17 '
'23513', '01/07/17 '
'9287', '05/07/17 '`

Comment: You didn't tried using `group by week(STR_TO_DATE(a.datecreated,'%d/%m/%y'))`

Comment: Just try once and you will get exact result what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Should use:

```
GROUP BY WEEK(a.datecreated, 7)
```

Or look at the [documentation of function `WEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) for the value of the second argument.